# How to change dmesg output colors in terminal?

Tags: terminal, colors, dmesg

There are some nasty colors in dmesg output. How to change this?
Looked into .Xresources and .bashrc, no colors defined there matched what I was searching for.

Comment: What have you learned from reading the manual page?

Comment: Xresources is for, well, X resources. Dmesg is not an X tool.

Comment: When a command doesn't do what you expect it to, do check its manpage: `manpage dmesg`. That's considered basic minimal research.

Comment: People, wtf, why all the downvotes? Is having the opinion that those colours are annoying worthy of such hate? We can disagree with the OP without being assholes. Jesus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dmesg` colours can be customised using a [`terminal-colors.d`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminal-colors.d.5.html) file. You can disable colours for `dmesg` by creating a file named `/etc/terminal-colors.d/dmesg.disable`, or build your own colour scheme by creating a file named `/etc/terminal-colors.d/dmesg.scheme`, containing one line per colour definition, *e.g.*

```
subsys red
```

to set the sub-system prefix to red.

If you don’t have a `terminal-colors.d` directory, create it first:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/terminal-colors.d
```

See [the “COLORS” section in `man dmesg`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html#COLORS) for the list of colour names supported, and [the scheme description in `man terminal-colors.d`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminal-colors.d.5.html#DEFAULT_SCHEME_FILES_FORMAT) for the values available for colours. To see what the `dmesg` default colours are, you’ll have to look at its source code, [the current defaults are](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/-/blob/e68b084f5a629cb9a0d61219dd821faa180dff75/sys-utils/dmesg.c#L81):

```c
static const struct dmesg_color colors[] =
{
    [DMESG_COLOR_SUBSYS]    = { "subsys",   UL_COLOR_BROWN },
    [DMESG_COLOR_TIME]  = { "time",     UL_COLOR_GREEN },
    [DMESG_COLOR_TIMEBREAK] = { "timebreak",UL_COLOR_GREEN UL_COLOR_BOLD },
    [DMESG_COLOR_ALERT] = { "alert",    UL_COLOR_REVERSE UL_COLOR_RED },
    [DMESG_COLOR_CRIT]  = { "crit",     UL_COLOR_BOLD UL_COLOR_RED },
    [DMESG_COLOR_ERR]       = { "err",      UL_COLOR_RED },
    [DMESG_COLOR_WARN]  = { "warn",     UL_COLOR_BOLD },
    [DMESG_COLOR_SEGFAULT]  = { "segfault", UL_COLOR_HALFBRIGHT UL_COLOR_RED }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

With a lot of these tools that have been gratuitously colored, the easiest way to uncolor them is to pipe them through `cat`.

```
$ dmesg | cat
```